# Angular2 UID as primary key using Firebase Database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

Im creating a signup component in my app using Firebase as Auth method and Database. When I register a new user, a key is generated and then I save all the user info including the UID from authentication in my database.
What I want to do is to use UID from authentication as my primary key instead of the key generated by Firebase.

This is my code:

component.ts

```
  signupUser(user: User) {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Success!', value);
        this.afdb.list('users').push({
          firstname: user.firstname,
          lastname: user.lastname,
          email: user.email,
          uid: value.uid
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
      });
  }
```

json in Firebase

```
users {
    -KpgNYJ0adjVyOGJiyBF {
        email: test@test.com
        firstname: dasdsa
        lastname: dsadsads
        uid: 021oxk8X6rQL6gAfC0UhZpB4vZx2
        }
    }
```

What I want

```
users {
    021oxk8X6rQL6gAfC0UhZpB4vZx2 {
        email: test@test.com
        firstname: dasdsa
        lastname: dsadsads
        }
    }
```

Your help is deeply appreciated as always. Thanks.

EDIT:
I forgot to tell  Im using AngularFire2.

Comment: Are you using AngularFire?

Comment: yes @robbannn I forgot to say it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `update` instead of `push`. `push` creates a new node and a unique key for that node. While `update` updates the specified node, or creates it if it doesn't already exist.

```
signupUser(user: User) {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then(value => {
        console.log('Success!', value);

        let userDetails = {
            firstname: user.firstname,
            lastname: user.lastname,
            email: user.email
        }

        this.afdb.list('users').update(value.uid, userDetails);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: Im using AngularFire2. Sorry for not saying that before.

Comment: Then I'm getting a typing error in this line `this.afdb.list('users').update(userDetails);`

it says that is expecting 2 arguments and not one.

Comment: I suspect youre using an older version than that in the docs. See the edit I made.