# AngularFire2 Database modeling. Saving data to multiple path

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm learning to use Firebase Database with Angular. I managed to create an auth service and to save the userinfo in Firebase Database. Im writing an app where users can buy a product and I need to link the transaction with the user.
This is the current state of my database:

```
users {
    021oxk8X6rQL6gAfC0UhZpB4vZx2 {
        email: test@test.com
        firstName: dasdsa
        lastName: dsadsads
        }
    }

transactions {
    DS766jdF6rQL6gAfC0Uh43Jhfw {
        product: thing
        price: 1000
        }
    }
```

This is what I need

```
transactions {
    DS766jdF6rQL6gAfC0Uh43Jhfw {
        product: thing
        price: 1000
        buyer: 021oxk8X6rQL6gAfC0UhZpB4vZx2 (User Key)
        }
    }

transactionsPerUser {
    021oxk8X6rQL6gAfC0UhZpB4vZx2 (User Key) {
        transaction: DS766jdF6rQL6gAfC0Uh43Jhfw (Transaction Key)
        }
    }
```

My code is this:

Database Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class DbfirebaseService {

  TransData: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  postData(info: TransData) {
    this.db.list('transactions').push({
      product: info.product,
      price: info.price,
    });
    console.log(info);
  }

}

interface TransData {
  product: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Component.ts

```
myForm: FormGroup;
error = false;
errorMessage = '';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private dbfr: DbfirebaseService) {
}

onSub() {
    this.dbfr.postData(this.myForm.value);
}

ngOnInit(): any {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        firstname: [''],
        lastname: [''],
    });
}
```

So, I have to questions. First one is how can I update my code to save the data the way I need to. And the second one is if this is the proper way to model my data in a NoSql Database?

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you searched for NoSql Database guides? I notice you've asked [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260292/angular2-uid-as-primary-key-using-firebase-database) without much research - let us know what you've done already

Comment: Thanks for your reply @0mpurdy. I did search for that, thats why I know its not good to do nesting. Its best to keep the data flat and thats why I used transactionsPerUser. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly though.

About the coding part, I tried inserting $key inside postData() but I'm getting undefined.

It's not my intention to ask without research. It's just that there aren't much resources involving Angular and Firebase. Also, AngularFire2 was updated a few weeks ago so most of the resources aren't updated with the latest version.

Comment: You could add what you have mentioned in your comment to the question - it means a lot to people answering to see what you have tried already! You could also look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some pointers

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for that. I'm going to open a new thread with more precise info regarding just one of the steps I asked here. Thanks for your time!